# How to enable detailed logging and track internal actions?

Tags: eclipse

I'm an Eclipse IDE user, and I've been curious about how to gain more insight into the inner workings of Eclipse. Specifically, I'm interested in enabling detailed logging to understand what's happening behind the scenes, such as which projects are being compiled with which makefiles, and other internal actions that Eclipse might be performing during various operations.

Is there a way to enable advanced logging in Eclipse to capture these details? Are there any plugins or runtime options that I should be aware of?

Comment: Look at "General > Tracing" in the Preferences. Lots and lots of options but they generally require detailed knowledge of the code.